# WebClient doesn't exist on Windows Phone 8.1? Downloading html of site

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to get source code of some website.

I found this solution:

```
var html = System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(siteUrl);
```

But VisualStudio tells that WebClient does not exist in System.Net.

How to fix that? Or how to do it other way?

PS: does windows phone have some special tag which developers usually use when they looking for some code/solutions?

Comment: Just chiming in as I had this issue the other day. WebClient (and I'm sure other classes) are a bit stripped down when it comes to Silverlight (I was using cordova with some C# for WP8).

Answer (score 12):

WebClient does exist in WP8 like this:

```
WebClient thisclient = new WebClient();
thisclent.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("urihere");
thisclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, x) =>
{
    if (x.Error != null)
    {
    //Catch any errors
    }
//Run Code
}
```

For 8.1 apps, use something like this:

```
    HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync("somesite");
    webresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

WebClient is available for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps.
Windows Phone Runtime apps use [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx).

There is also a [Portable HttpClient for .NET Framework and Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently use to download HTML source from webpages:

```
public static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string pageURL)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

This function will return downloaded html of pageURL.