# HTML Agility get text from paragraph tags in a div

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the text of paragraph tags in a div using htmlagilitypack 2.28 in a windows phone 8.1 app.

The structure of div is

```
<div id="55">

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span class="dropcap">W

</span><span class="zw-portion"><strong>ith the start of festive season in India</strong>, we   
will also witness the f<strong>irst London Derby</strong> of the season    
between the newly London rivals <strong>Chelsea and Arsenal</strong>. It will be a great chance  
for Arsene Wenger to get rid of his <strong>1000</strong></span>

<strong><span class="zw-portion">th</span><span class="zw-portion"> managed </span>

<span class="zw-portion">6-0 </spa>  

<span class="zw-portion">massacre</span></strong>

<span class="zw-portion"> in March,</span>

<span class="zw-portion">&nbsp;</span>

<span class="zw-portion">while the Special One will be eager to continue his winning rampage  
</span>

<span class="zw-portion">&nbsp;</span>

<span class="zw- portion">over his “<strong>Specialist in Failure</strong>” counterpart. Although 
both clubs can boast of being unbeaten this season and both clubs can take this opportunity 
</span>

<span class="zw-portion"> to bring down their rival</span><span class="zw-portion">.</span></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zFBN8M1pCxo?  
feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>

<p class="zw-paragraph" data-textformat="
{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;text&quot;,&quot;td&quot;:&quot;none&quot;}"></p>

<p class="zw-paragraph" data-textformat=   
{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;text&quot;,&quot;td&quot;:&quot;none&quot;}">

<span class="zw-portion">The rivalry between Chelsea and Arsenal was not as a primary London  
Derby, until Chelsea rose to top of Premier League in 2000’s, when they consistently competed 
against each other. The rivalry between the two clubs rose higher as compared to their 
traditional rivals. Both the clubs rivalry are now not only limited to their pitch but has also 
been to the fans. In 2009 survey by Football Fans Census, Arsenal fans named Chelsea as the 

<strong>most disliked club</strong>  </span>

<span class="zw-portion"> ahead of their traditional rivals <strong>Manchest</strong></span>
<strong> <span class="zw-portion">er United and Tottenham Hotspur</span></strong>

<span class="zw-portion">. However the report of the other camp doesn’t differ much as Chelsea 
fans ranks Arsenal as their <strong>second most-disliked club</strong></span>

<strong><span class="zw-portion">.
</span></strong></p>
</div>
```

I want to extract only the text containined within the paragraph element within the div.
I have written the following code so far where feedurl contains the address of page from which data is to be extracted (the correct address is extracted). After that i try to get a reference to the div using it's id (which is equal to 55 always).

```
var feedurl = GetValue("feedurl");
string htmlPage = "asdsad";
HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmldoc.LoadHtml(feedurl);
htmldoc.OptionUseIdAttribute=true;
HtmlNode div = htmldoc.GetElementbyId("55");
if (div != null)
{
    htmlPage += "done";
}

_content = htmlPage;
return _content;
```

`htmldoc.GetElementbyId("55");` is returning a null reference.
I've read to use `htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes([arguments])`. but there is not `SelectNodes` method available to me. And I'm lost on how to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack version for WP 8.1 doesn't support `SelectNodes()` because that method requires XPath implementation which unfortunately missing in .NET version for WP8.1.

The solution is to use HtmlAgilityPack's LINQ API instead of Xpath. For example, to get `<div>` element having `id` attribute equals `55`  :

```cs
HtmlNode div55 = htmldoc.DocumentNode
                        .Descendants("div")
                        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("id", "") 
                                                    == "55");
```

Comment: I'll have to use system.link, right.
And if after that I use
`if(div55!=null){do something}` it's not doing anything. And if I use `div55.InnerText` I get NullReference exception.

Comment: Make sure you loaded the HTML to `HtmlDocument` correctly  (you can check via `DocumentNode.OuterHtml` property, see if the property contain the expected HTML markup)

Comment: `DocumentNode.OuterHtml` is returning me back url of the page stored in `feedurl` variable. Is it correct. Forgive me for such stupid question since I'm new to htmlagility and can't find an answer on the net.

Comment: That's not correct. Should contain the HTML markup instead of the URL. You need to download the HTML from that URL first, then pass it to `LoadHtml()` method. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196538/2998271) for how to download HTML from URL in WP8.1 (though, I haven't verified if that's actually work)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got it done!!!  Used some help from [here](http://www.tareqateik.com/html-agility-pack%E2%80%93windows-phone-8#.VDKC0PmSylB) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452713.aspx) to get the source code of page. Then your code did the rest.