# How to download string from HTTPS website in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, https, httpwebrequest

I am windows phone developer, I want to download string from HTTPS web site and I use

```
WebClient most_down_download = new WebClient();
most_down_download.DownloadStringCompleted += Most_down_download_DownloadStringCompleted;
most_down_download.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(https_url));
```

but it is not working. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need generate `Most_down_download_DownloadStringCompleted` event handler as below

```
void Most_down_download_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, 
                              System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            string response = e.Result.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

And in `e.Result.ToString()` you are getting string from Web site

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Using HTTP Client instead of web Client (8.1)

```
HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(https_url);
webresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184968/webclient-doesnt-exist-on-windows-phone-8-1-downloading-html-of-site)

Comment: thanks you for your support, but it stils not working .

Comment: not error message,but output not fully html file behind